# AlpineJS trigger magic function programatically

Tags: alpine.js

I've been using this notification magic

```
<div x-init="$notification({text: 'my message', variant: 'error'})"></div>
```

It is working when you load the page. My goal is to trigger it by calling via javascript function.

I'm looking for ideas on how to implement that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [default events](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on) or [custom events](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch). Code is untested but something like this will work.

```html
<button x-on:click="$notification({text: 'clicked', variant: 'info'})">
    Click me
</button>

<button x-on:click="$dispatch('add-error', {message: 'Something went wrong'})">
    Click me
</button>

<div x-on:add-error.window="$notification({text: $event.detail.message, variant: 'error'})"></div>
```